# How to reinterpret an array of f64 as a tuple of f64 elements?

Tags: arrays, rust, tuples

I have a code generator which produces call to a function that returns `Vec<f64>`. I need to assign these values into a set of variables, and the best way seems to be a tuple of those variables. Something like this:

```rust
let array: &[f64] = &my_function(3);
let (a, b, c): (f64, f64, f64) = unsafe { std::mem::transmute(*array) };
```

[playground (uncompillable)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=333cdb2998f488b1e93f30e63bb4df56)

I did not figure out how to write the unsafe part to have it accepted by the compiler.

I prefer to avoid generating the item per item assignments, because performance is of huge importance here.

Can this be done? Is the memory layout of a tuple compatible with array?

Comment: *a function that returns `Vec<f64>`*  / *an array of f64* / *`&[f64]`* — These are **3** different types with different semantics. You need to understand that far before you attempt to do unsafe manipulation, but more importantly, you need to be precise in *this question* before you can get a useful answer.

Comment: *because performance is of huge importance here* — you are making a large assumption about the performance without showing any concrete data to back it up. Do the thing that works and see if it's fast enough. Leave a "TODO" comment if you feel strongly that it should be fixed.

Comment: highest possible performance is requirement, not an assumption - so if there was any chance for a construct that results in no-op on machine level, I just want to use it, no matter if it brings a little or a lot. Sadly it's not the case, thanks to your great answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do this, period; [tuples do not have a guaranteed memory layout](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.41.1/reference/type-layout.html#tuple-layout), therefore you cannot transmute from something that may or may not match.

I would do normal pattern matching:

```
fn main() {
    let values = my_function(3);
    dbg!(&values);
    let (a, b, c) = match &*values {
        [a, b, c] => (a, b, c),
        _ => panic!(),
    };
    dbg!(a, b, c);
}

fn my_function(count: usize) -> Vec<f64> {
    vec![3.14_0f64; count]
}
```

See also:

- [What is the memory layout of structs, tuples and tuple structs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25650128/155423)
- [How to convert a tuple of references to a reference of a tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56528652/155423)
- [Is it possible to control the size of an array using the type parameter of a generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28136739/155423)

Answer (score 1):

Using const generics and new feature that allows to convert arrays back and forth:

```rust
fn main() {
    let array = my_function::<3>();
    let (a, b, c): (f64, f64, f64) = array.into();
}

fn my_function<const N: usize>() -> [f64; N] {
    [0.0; N]
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer since the array-to-tuple [`From` implementations](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html#impl-From%3C(T,)%3E-for-%5BT;+1%5D) were recently added. Though you should also address that OP has a `Vec` (not an array) and so these conversions aren't directly available. Perhaps mention using [`TryFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html#impl-TryFrom%3CVec%3CT,+A%3E%3E-for-%5BT;+N%5D) for that?